# "have/has condition" or "need condition"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

Yesterday, I put a message in a social network environment to inform other members about lottery:
"Lottery for year 2016 is now open, try your chance. It does not have any especial condition." 
But a member answered:
"'It does not need' is closer to English instead of 'does not have' ."
Are both forms grammatically correct? and which of them is more common and suitable?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you give an example or two of what might be "special conditions?" For instance, in the USA, one has to be a certain age (18 or 21 or something) to buy a lottery ticket. So most state lotteries *have* this special condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both constructs feel kind of odd to me, though yours (*"It does not have..."*) feels less awkward. A lottery can't *own* conditions, nothing can. Therefore it cannot be said to *have special conditions*. Nor can a lottery *need* conditions. That, to me, makes it sound like a living thing, that must be fed conditions in order for it to survive. I know, this sounds a bit mental, but there's a connotation of this lottery being an actual living organism with both your phrasings. I'd put it like this:

> The 2016 lottery is now open, try your luck. No special conditions apply.

But still, the *"no special conditions apply"* is rather vague. This can be taken to mean that this lottery is a *no strings attached* kind of deal; or that there are no conditions that apply, other than those that normally do (in most countries that I know of, there's an age restriction, some people might be prohibited to gamble for other legal reasons, like people probation might be prohibited to gamble). In that case, I suspect it's common to write something like:

> The 2016 lottery is now open, test your luck. (*)
>   (*) Some legal dribble stating that participants must be over a given age, mustn't do this or that etc...